# Получение данных из таблицы

Tags: php

Пытаюсь получить логин из таблицы БД, но в итоге выдает просто слово login

```
    $COOKIE=$_COOKIE['id'];
    $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT 'login' FROM `user` where id=$COOKIE");
    while($row= $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC))
{
echo $row['login'];
}
```

Comment: Проверьте массив var_dump($row); и возможно все проянится

Answer (score 1):

> Пытаюсь получить логин из таблицы БД, но в итоге выдает просто слово login

Ошибка в запросе. Не нужны ковычки `'login'` в названии столбца таблицы.

Поменяйте на:

```
$mysqli->query("SELECT login FROM user where id=$COOKIE");
```

---

P.S.: `$COOKIE=$_COOKIE['id'];` надо бы это экранировать, как-нибудь, что бы не получить нежелательные последствия.

Например так:

```
$cookies = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_COOKIE['id']);
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT login FROM `user` where id='$cookies'");
```

---

**UPD:** благодарю @vp_arth

Если `$_COOKIE['id']` содержит только числовое значение, то будет лучше экранировать функцией *intval* учитывая размер числа и т.д.

Comment: Арргх. Не используйте функцию для экранирования строк на данных целочисленного типа. intval в этом месте справится гораздо лучше.